# Redirect control from one controller to an other

Tags: sencha-touch-2

How can I "redirect" control from one controller to an other? Is it through events/listener ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, event/listener is a way to do it. Alternatively, you can call any method of any controller from any place in your application through this:

```
Ext.getApplication().getController("your_target_controller").method_name()
```

Comment: cool, thanks, didnt know about that twist you showed there. Solved my problem by registering event listener and fire events, saw that light after I understood Sencha 2 flow is built around sending events on an event bus.